# How to integrate a deep reinforcement learning model developed using Python and PyTorch into AnyLogic

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, anylogic, reinforcement-learning

How to utilize a pre-established deep reinforcement learning model with AnyLogic as both a training and testing environment?

It is possible to export an AnyLogic model and use a deep reinforcement learning model for training, or alternatively, embed the deep reinforcement learning model into AnyLogic. I have only found information on exporting AnyLogic models and using Java for training with a deep reinforcement learning model. I am unsure whether it is feasible to export an AnyLogic model, train it using Python and PyTorch, and then import it back into AnyLogic for training and testing.

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Else, try to break down your broad question into specific sub-questions and ask them separately, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow. Welcome again, happy to help